# kiwi-tcms: kiwi_db restarting loop

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I am trying to install kiwi-tcms and when I get to step:

```
docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py initial_setup
```

---

```
D:\path\to\kiwi-tcms>docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py initial_setup
```

1. Applying migrations:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
> self.connect()
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
> self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
> connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 130, in Connect
> return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in **init**
> super().**init**(*args, **kwargs2)
> MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (-2)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Kiwi/manage.py", line 12, in 
> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
> utility.execute()
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 413, in execute
> self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
> self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
> output = self.handle(*args, **options)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tcms/core/management/commands/initial_setup.py", line 11, in handle
> call_command("migrate", "--verbosity=%i" % kwargs["verbosity"])
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 181, in call_command
> return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
> output = self.handle(*args, **options)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
> res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 92, in handle
> executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in **init**
> self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in **init**
> self.build_graph()
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 220, in build_graph
> self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
> if self.has_table():
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
> with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
> return self._cursor()
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
> self.ensure_connection()
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
> self.connect()
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in **exit**
> raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
> self.connect()
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
> self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
> connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 130, in Connect
> return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in **init**
> super().**init**(*args, **kwargs2)
> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (-2)")

---

I'm working windows 10. I also have the `kiwi_db` that is constantly restarted in docker

Answer (score 0):

> Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (-2)"

The error message itself is clear enough. Your DB server doesn't seem to be up and running.

> I'm working windows 10. I also have the kiwi_db that is constantly restarted in docker

Kiwi TCMS and MySQL/MariaDB are Linux based containers so maybe your Windows host is not capable of running Linux containers in the first place. Refer to Docker's documentation/support on that matter.

This may be of help but fair warning that it's been written by a 3rd party not affiliated with the Kiwi TCMS team:
https://medium.com/@siriwardhane.yuwin/running-kiwi-tcms-as-a-docker-container-in-windows-10-home-82d74b107202